# How to perform hex encoding in Elixir?

Tags: javascript, encoding, hex, elixir

Why in JavaScript I have:

```
Buffer.from("32038ca6aa25db9377aaf54ac2de4059419205e4b9021b68a3b83039a5742b1f0d55cd39c3b8369373507963209c9676ac230d4724cb343b26a3cba4d6c84cae")

// Uint8Array(128) [51, 50, 48, 51, 56, 99, 97, 54, 97, 97, 50, 53, 100, 98, 57, 51, 55, 55, 97, 97, 102, 53, 52, 97, 99, 50, 100, 101, 52, 48, 53, 57, 52, 49, 57, 50, 48, 53, 101, 52, 98, 57, 48, 50, 49, 98, 54, 56, 97, 51, 98, 56, 51, 48, 51, 57, 97, 53, 55, 52, 50, 98, 49, 102, 48, 100, 53, 53, 99, 100, 51, 57, 99, 51, 98, 56, 51, 54, 57, 51, 55, 51, 53, 48, 55, 57, 54, 51, 50, 48, 57, 99, 57, 54, 55, 54, 97, 99, 50, 51, …]

Buffer.from("32038ca6aa25db9377aaf54ac2de4059419205e4b9021b68a3b83039a5742b1f0d55cd39c3b8369373507963209c9676ac230d4724cb343b26a3cba4d6c84cae", 'hex')

// Uint8Array(64) [50, 3, 140, 166, 170, 37, 219, 147, 119, 170, 245, 74, 194, 222, 64, 89, 65, 146, 5, 228, 185, 2, 27, 104, 163, 184, 48, 57, 165, 116, 43, 31, 13, 85, 205, 57, 195, 184, 54, 147, 115, 80, 121, 99, 32, 156, 150, 118, 172, 35, 13, 71, 36, 203, 52, 59, 38, 163, 203, 164, 214, 200, 76, 174]
```

While in Elixir I get:

```
iex(1)> "32038ca6aa25db9377aaf54ac2de4059419205e4b9021b68a3b83039a5742b1f0d55cd39c3b8369373507963209c9676ac230d4724cb343b26a3cba4d6c84cae" <> <<0>>
<<51, 50, 48, 51, 56, 99, 97, 54, 97, 97, 50, 53, 100, 98, 57, 51, 55, 55, 97, 97, 102, 53, 52, 97, 99, 50, 100, 101, 52, 48, 53, 57, 52, 49, 57, 50, 48, 53, 101, 52, 98, 57, 48, 50, 49, 98, 54, 56, 97, 51, ...>>
```

but:

```
iex(2)> Base.encode16("32038ca6aa25db9377aaf54ac2de4059419205e4b9021b68a3b83039a5742b1f0d55cd39c3b8369373507963209c9676ac230d4724cb343b26a3cba4d6c84cae") <> <<0>>
<<51, 51, 51, 50, 51, 48, 51, 51, 51, 56, 54, 51, 54, 49, 51, 54, 54, 49, 54, 49, 51, 50, 51, 53, 54, 52, 54, 50, 51, 57, 51, 51, 51, 55, 51, 55, 54, 49, 54, 49, 54, 54, 51, 53, 51, 52, 54, 49, 54, 51, ...>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the Base 16 *decode* function, not *encode*:

```
iex(1)> Base.decode16!("32038ca6aa25db9377aaf54ac2de4059419205e4b9021b68a3b83039a5742b1f0d55cd39c3b8369373507963209c9676ac230d4724cb343b26a3cba4d6c84cae", case: :lower) <> <<0>>
<<50, 3, 140, 166, 170, 37, 219, 147, 119, 170, 245, 74, 194, 222, 64, 89, 65,
  146, 5, 228, 185, 2, 27, 104, 163, 184, 48, 57, 165, 116, 43, 31, 13, 85, 205,
  57, 195, 184, 54, 147, 115, 80, 121, 99, 32, 156, 150, 118, 172, 35, ...>>
```

Comment: OMG, what a shame! Thank you! Is there a better way than `<> <<0>>` BTW?

Comment: You can use `inspect` or `IO.inspect` with the `binaries` option: `IO.inspect <<40, 50>>, binaries: :as_binaries` but I use `<> <<0>>` as it's shorter.